# Laravel flush session with some exceptions

Tags: laravel

```
Session::flush();

Session::forget('name');
Session::forget('account');
Session::forget('name');
... and more
('locale'); //flush all session and only keep this session
```

Is possible to flush all session with some exceptions

I have many sessions, when user logout I want to flush all with some exceptions.

If I use forget, it seems a bit hard for me to maintenance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can see 2 alternatives here.

1- If you know everything you want to forget, pass them as an array

```
Session::forget(['account', 'name']);
```

2- If you only want to keep one item, get it first, flush the session, put it back

```
$locale = Session::get('locale');
Session::flush();
Session::put('locale', $locale);
```